# Unmounted fstab entries showing up in GTK open dialogs

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, gtk

I have written entries in /etc/fstab for an extensive bunch of removable drives. All these entries, even unmounted and unplugged, appear in ANY GTK file open dialog, which is definitely a nuisance. I just want to have the mounted drives appear in the file dialog, but not the drives which are on the shelf. Is this feasible?

PS : I use Debian 8/Jessie.

Comment: One way that several distros performs this that instead of having a huge `fstab` they run thunar/nautilus as a daemon which pools for new devices, and then mount them.  Also, it might be useful to post your `fstab`.

Comment: Thanks grochmal for your answer.  I have no need for automouting and usually don’t even use nautilus etc. I just want to mount (manually)  the same flash drive or external hard disk always in the same directory.  That’s why I have given all my external drives specific labels. and use them in fstab, e.g.

LABEL=CRUZF32_03 /mnt/CRUZF32_03 auto rw,user,noauto,exec 0 0
<b/>OR
LABEL=cassis3 /mnt/cassis3 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,errors=remount-ro 0 0